# Calculate quadrant for triangles inside a rectangle

Tags: javascript

I have the following method that calculates a quadrant in a square with an equal width and height divided by four triangles:

```
function getQuadtrant(x, y, width, height){
    if(y < width/2 && x < width-y && x > y) {

    alert('top triangle');

    }

    if(y > width/2 && x > width-y && x < y) {

    alert('bottom triangle');

    }

    if(x < height/2 && x < width-y && x < y) {

    alert('left triangle');

    }


    if(x > height/2 && x > width-y && x > y) {

    alert('right triangle');

    }
}
```

However, I have a div that is rectangular with a width of 249px and a height of 404px, how do I get the quadrant? With the above code in it's current state gives an erroneous output, when I select a particular area of a triangle for example the top triangle it alerts 'bottom triangle'.

Comment: "With the above code in it's current state gives an erroneous output." --- and we need to guess it?

Comment: @zerkms My apologies, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do that in this way:

```
function getQ(x, y, w, h) {
    var quadrants = [
        ['left', 'top'],
        ['bottom', 'right']
    ];

    if (y > h / w * x) {
        quadrants = quadrants[0];
    } else {
        quadrants = quadrants[1];
    }

    return (y < -h / w * x + h) ? quadrants[0] : quadrants[1];
}


console.log(getQ(10, 20, 20, 20));​
```

This solution is pretty trivial and based on diagonal lines equations. If the `y` is above the main diagonal - then it's either `left` or `top` (`quadrants[0]`). If the `y` is below the secondary diagonal - it's `left`, otherwise it's `top`. The same for bottom part.

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/aCAfw/

Comment: @Imran Azad: from my perspective this solution is **much** clearer

Comment: Yes you're right, I must admit it is a lot easier to read and follow.

Comment: Came across this elegant solution in 2021. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Your first two tests are comparing `y` to `width/2`, whereas I think it should be comparing to `height/2` instead.

EDIT: Here's some revised code that works for all rectangles instead of just squares:

```
function getQuadrant(x,y,width,height) {
    var l = {x:x-width/2,y:y-height/2}, // "local" coords - origin at centre
        g = l.x/width*height; // "gradient" - position on diagonal
    if( l.y < -g && l.y < g) alert("Top");
    else if( l.y < -g && l.y >= g) alert("Right");
    else if( l.y >= -g && l.y >= g) alert("Bottom");
    else if( l.y >= -g && l.y < g) alert("Left");
    else alert("Tell Kolink he messed up");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that almost worked! The problem is that now the top portion of the triangle close to the vertix doesn't alert anything at all, whereas it should alert 'top triangle'.

Comment: I suspect that the `width-y` should be `height-y`. However that said your code needs revising since it fails for non-square elements.